# How to convert .csv to .npz in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a csv file which is just an excel sheet with 9x32 values that I would like to convert to a npz file.

I've tried creating an array using np.zeros([9,32]) and then loading the csv file from a path, but it doesn't seem to be working (I might also be completely off).

Thanks!

Comment: An `npz` file is actually a `zip` archive created by the `numpy.savez` function.  That means you need to load the `csv` into a numpy array.  Once done, writing the `npz` (or just a `npy`) is straight forward (provided you follow the function docs).

Comment: _I've tried creating an array using np.zeros([9,32]) and then loading the csv file from a path, but it doesn't seem to be working_ I'm not sure how much we can help going off of that information only.

Answer (score 1):

It's preety straightforward to do so. Start by loading csv in numpy using

```
my_data = np.genfromtxt(path_of_csv, delimiter=',')
```

and to save it in npz use

```
np.save('my_dat.npy', my_data)
```

Comment: be careful with this method! if the csv has "headers" or columns titles, 'np.save' method take it and it turns into in a 'nan' row

Answer (score 1):

If you have a very large CSV file then np.genfromtxt() becomes very inefficient. You can instead use Pandas dataframe to read the CSV file and convert into a numpy array:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(path_of_csv, delimiter=',')
df = df.to_numpy()
np.save('my_data', df)
```